# @CrossOrigin not working for spring-boot-starter-web 2.5.2

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, rest, cors

I have Spring Boot rest controller which exposes certain APIs which I want to consume in Angular 12.
On the controller I have added @CrossOrigin, but spring-boot does not seem to pick it up because even after adding the annotation I am getting the Cors policy issue.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)
@RequestMapping("api/rest")
public class MyController {
```

[cors error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n9Sh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've enabled the cross-origin for the particular controller. Either you can enable the same by adding the `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` on other controllers **or** you can configured the cross-origin globally by creating the bean as following

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding it as `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:<your_port>")`

Where `your_port` is the port your angular app is using?

Answer (score -1):

Try following code:

```java
@CrossOrigin(allowCredentials = "true")
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a CORS-Origin extension to your browser if you are sending request from the browser. If @CrossOrigin doesn't work then thats your problem. There you go:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino